# Eclipse Crash and Not Regenerate R.java

Tags: android, eclipse

I know this question has been asked & answered before.  But, none of those answers work for me.  Eclipse crashed in the middle of a build and keeps erasing the R.java file.  I have tried to clean and rebuild.  Does not help.  I was using SDK build tools 19.0 upgraded to 20.0.  Does not help.  I didn't touch anything in the XML files and I do not see any errors in the XML files.

Comment: there must be compilation error in your project. open problem windows and see what needs to be fixed other than references to R.java .

Comment: try cleaning project

Comment: He specifically said that he tried that

Comment: the only problems i can see are in the source files referencing R.layout.something   But, I don't see anything in the xml, string or layout files.  No errors, no missing, no used.

Answer (score 0):

Try another IDE e.g [Idea](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) and check if this is due to your Eclipse malfunction not your SDK that you have updated recently

Comment: I do have an older version of Eclipse in a different environment.   I tried immporting the project into that environment and cleaning in the other environment. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I my case there was something wrong with my XML usually my `layout` files, when you have a problem in your XML files the clean option does not work properly,  check your XML files ( `layout` and `manifest` ) and after that clean your project.

Hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

I did get my R.java back.  There was a jpeg for another project stuck in a drawable directory.  Don't know how it got there.  and, still lots of unexplained errors though.

Answer (score 0):

All my other errors were from switch statements using R.something_menu.icon for cases handling user responses.   I got a message that as of ADT 14, switch statements can no longer be used.  I had to migrate to if...else   It works.  Don't know why.  But, it solved the problem & saved my code.